# Force update notifications for DependencyProperty even when it doesn't change

Tags: .net, wpf, custom-controls, dependency-properties

I have a custom WPF control. It has a typical `DependencyProperty`, let's call it `Status`, which is updated periodically via binding. (More specifically, it is bound to a property which sends notifications according to `INotifyPropertyChanged`).

I want to implement a certain 'expiration' behaviour: if `Status` is not updated for a certain time, something happens. Ideally, this logics should be within my custom control (I have many instances of it). I set up a `DispatcherTimer` in the `Status` change handler and do what I need. All fine.

The problem is, usually, `Status` is updated to the same value, i.e. doesn't actually change. Yet even in this case it should reset the expiration timer.

Even if I force my view model (that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`) to send the notifications on assignment regardless of whether the value changed, the WPF `DependencyProperty` implementation is smart enough to check for the change on its own, and it doesn't call my `PropertyChangeCallback` that I registered for `Status` (in `FrameworkPropertyMetadata`).

What is the best thing to do?

I could create another `DependencyProperty` in my control that I would always change upon assignment to `Status` (say, assign a random number or flip a `bool`), and do my timer handling there. But this seems to be an ugly and very roundabout way, especially to use.

Comment: If your status is text, just create a wrapper class Status which has a property for the text and when updating always create a new instance.

Comment: @JanneMatikainen, no it's an int, but it's a valid idea nevertheless...

Answer (score 0):

Just to answer my own question and provide at least some solution, in the end I did what @Janne suggested. I made a wrapper class over `int`, so each assignment created a new object and was treated as such. (I did not override the `Equals` method to do numerical comparison of the `Status`, so the DP could only use object identity check).

As a downside, this must create a lot of small garbage (there are 100+ real-time assignments per second over the whole life of the app), but this wasn't problematic; esp. given that WPF boxes everything anyway.