# Force a dependencyproperty to always call PropretyChangedCallback

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have a CustomControl with a "SetState" DependencyProperty. That is bound to a MultiBinding (one-way) with converter. That all works.

So everything is properly updated, PropertyChanged event is fired, converter gets the values, generates the output value but the SetState proeprty is not updated IF it is for example true and the converter yields to true as well. Since i want the reset logic (see code below) to execute i want SetState always to be updated even though the value it will be set to is the same as the current value.
(if the converter results in false and SetState is true SetState will be properly updated to false as expected)

---

MWE (typed on the fly pardon my errors)

View

```
    <local:CustomControl>
        <local:CustomControl.SetState>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{local:MyConverter}">
                <Binding Path="MyProp1" Mode="OneWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"/>
                <Binding Path="MyProp2" Mode="OneWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"/>
            </MultiBinding>
        </local:CustomControl.SetState>
    </local:CustomControl>
```

Custom Control

```
   public class CustomControl : FrameworkElement
   {
      public static readonly DependencyProperty IsExpandedProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
              nameof(SetState),
              typeof(bool),
              typeof(CustomControl),
              new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false, (s, e) =>
              {
                 ((CustomControl)s).SetState = (bool)e.NewValue;
              }));

      private bool _state;

      // For brevity i have used a boolean in the MWE
      public bool SetState
      {
         get { return _state; }
         set
         {
            // This is not called when the binding produces the same value as this property already has
            // but i want this to be set anyway to trigger the reset logic even though SetState property already equal the value being set.

            // Custom reset logic here

            _state = value;
         }
      }
   }
```

Converter

```
  internal class MyConverter : MarkupExtension, IMultiValueConverter
   {
      private static MyConverter _instance;

      public object Convert(object[] value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
      {
         // Imagine some complex logic here
         return ((bool)value[0] || (bool)value[1]);
      }

      public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
      {
         throw new NotImplementedException();
      }

      public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
      {
         return _instance ?? (_instance = new MyConverter());
      }
   }
```

View model

```
   internal class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
   {
      private bool _myProp1;
      private bool _myProp2;

      // Imagine the properties being altered at run-time

      public bool MyProp1
      {
         get { return _myProp1; }
         private set { _myProp1 = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
      }

      public bool MyProp2
      {
         get { return _myProp2; }
         private set { _myProp2 = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
      }

      public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

      private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
      {
         PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
      }
   }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Please provide your code so that we can help.

Comment: Not sure what exactly you are trying to achieve, but even if you could force the Binding to produce a new value, the target dependency property will not actually change, and hence not call its PropertyChangedCallback (if that is what you intended).

Comment: Clarified and added example code (not really a run-able example but it should get the point across, i hope)

Comment: What @Clemens is saying is indeed likely the cause, i assume it was due to the binding but looks like it is due to the dependency property. Question is what is a possible solution/work-around? Seems like my question is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38654075/force-update-notifications-for-dependencyproperty-even-when-it-doesnt-change although the proposed solution there is not really satisfactory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution ended up being rather [simple](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/cd3c7660-af38-42dc-aa40-de78b91bc914/wpf-force-dependencyproperty-change-from-the-code?forum=wpf), for the DependencyProperty use the [CoerceValueCallback](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.coercevaluecallback?view=netframework-4.7.2) instead of the [PropertyChangedCallback](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.propertychangedcallback?view=netframework-4.7.2). The former is always called, the later only if the value has actually been changed.

So in code it becomes

```
  public static readonly DependencyProperty IsExpandedProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
          nameof(SetState),
          typeof(bool),
          typeof(CustomControl),
      new PropertyMetadata(false, null,
         (d, v) =>
         {
            ((CollapsibleColumnDefinition)d).IsExpanded = (bool)v;
            return v;
         }));
```

I briefly tried to manually force the dependency property to refresh (note [bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4926748/dependencyobject-invalidateproperty-not-working)) but the CoerceValueCallback does exactly what i wanted and is cleaner.